# Sanitize Array inside save_post

Tags: wordpress, sanitize

Let's say I have array like this :

```
   Array (

   [2066] => Array (
        [images_id] => 2066
        [title] => title one)

   [2063] => Array (
        [images_id] => 2063
        [title] => title two )

   [2022] => Array (
        [images_id] => 2022
        [title] => title three )

   )
```

or in database format like this:

```
    a:3:{i:2066;a:2:{s:8:"image_id";s:4:"2066";s:5:"title";s:9:"Title One";}i:2063;a:2:{s:8:"image_id";s:4:"2063";s:5:"title";s:9:"Title Two";}i:2022;a:2:{s:8:"image_id";s:4:"2022";s:5:"title";s:11:"Title Three";}}
```

How to sanitize with *esc_attr* or *sanitize_text_field* for **images_id** and **title** ?

Any help really appreciated :)

Comment: Actually, what you want to do? Please clarify a little more

Comment: @Reza Mamun please check edited post above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sanitize the `images_id` and the `title` fields of the array with Wordpress's [esc_attr()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) and [sanitize_text_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) functions using the PHP's [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) like below:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
   2066 => array (
        'images_id' => 2066,
        'title' => 'title one'
   ),
   2063 => array (
        'images_id' => 2063,
        'title' => 'title two'
   ),
   2022 => array (
        'images_id' => 2022,
        'title' => 'title three'
   )
);

//Sanitizing here:
array_walk($arr, function(&$value, &$key) {
    $value['images_id'] = esc_attr($value['images_id']);
    $value['title'] = esc_attr($value['title']);

    //--AND/OR--
    $value['images_id'] = sanitize_text_field($value['images_id']);
    $value['title'] = sanitize_text_field($value['title']);
});

//Now check the new array:
echo '<pre>'; print_r($arr); echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much :)